# Is it possible to add jquery or javascript code dynamically?

Tags: jquery

I have this textbox. When a user writes some Jquery code in the textbox and click Apply. I want the code applied to Html page. The code is being appended to body but the generated click function is not working. I have also tried appending the code to HEAD also, click doen't work this way too. Is it possible that it works?

My Html code is

```
  <span id="clickme">Click Me</span>
  <textarea id="txt">
  $('#clickme').click(function(){
       alert("clicked");
    });
  </textarea>
  <button id="apply">Apply</button>
```

My Jquery is

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#apply',function(){
  var code=$('#txt').val();
  $('body').append('<script type="text/javascript">'+code+'</script>');

  });
  });
```

Comment: Congratulations, you found a use-case of `eval`.

Comment: I have no idea of eval. Can you help me with this code, if i wanted to do it in Jquery?

Comment: Your jQuery code, where is it? In the page or in separate file?

Comment: @Serge I have tried both ways. On the page & separate file. Not working

Comment: @Manish you might be better off doing what zzzzBov mention and use eval. You can try something like this: eval($('#txt').val());  That should execute whatever was typed into the text box on the apply button click. I would also highly recommend you wrap the eval statement in a try catch to prevent issues with miss typed code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a note, typically `eval` is considered *evil*. That's because it's often (ab)used when it's the wrong tool for the job. In this case, however, you simply want to run some ambiguous code, which means you're already giving control of your page directly to the user.

---

[`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) evaluates JavaScript code directly as a string. There's no reason to try to add it to the page as a `script` element, when you could simply call:

```
$(document).on('click', '#apply', function () {
    try {
        eval($('#txt').val());
    } catch (ex) {
        //might as well report to the console what went wrong
        window.console&&console.error(ex.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you included jquery itself in your page? I copypasted your code and it works http://jsfiddle.net/2R8wX/

(Except I added `<body>` and split `</script>`)

Comment: It should also be noted that older versions of jQuery won't allow you to inject `<script>` elements and have them execute.